# Does anyone know how to install and use a Gemalto Card Reader for AKO?

Tags: smartcard

I would like to migrate my office work to this home computer, and I need to use a smart card reader to access military applications.  Windows has a built-in smart card program, and I was hoping that this release of Ubuntu might as well.  Thank you.